# I'm developing an application in Python, using Selenium, and to make it work, I need Chrome to open with a session started

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want my Chrome to open when logged in, so I don't have to go through capthas, etc. Here is my code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

options = Options()

options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\')

driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver'


driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)

sleep(5)

print('hello world')

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
```

And until it works, it opens Chrome already logged in, but the selenim part doesn't work, it just opens Google and stays there, doesn't print anything, doesn't go to Instagram, or anything.

The following error appears in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\Tts\tts.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 466, in __init__    
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__  
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__ 
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 724, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:61804
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010ECE43+45171]
        (No symbol) [0x01079091]
        (No symbol) [0x00F6BCE0]
        (No symbol) [0x00F60D21]
        (No symbol) [0x00F93A38]
        (No symbol) [0x00F8D73C]
        (No symbol) [0x00F8D56F]
        (No symbol) [0x00FC1AA6]
        (No symbol) [0x00FC163C]
        (No symbol) [0x00FBAE46]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9675E]
        (No symbol) [0x00F978FD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013A5449+2897529]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013EDBFB+3194411]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013E79D1+3169281]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011760C0+606960]
        (No symbol) [0x01082E0C]
        (No symbol) [0x0107EF98]
        (No symbol) [0x0107F0BF]
        (No symbol) [0x010717B7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x777200C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C07B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C07AEE+238]
```

I noticed that if I comment the line "driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')", it doesn't change anything, that is, it opens the browser already when naming the driver, which I don't think should happen.

I'm using python3.11

I've tried many things, changing the python version; change the chromedriver version; etc. I want, in addition to opening the already started session, the Selenium functions to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply using Selenium as below:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

# Specify the Chrome profile directory to use (Profile 2)
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')

# Specify the user data directory where Chrome profile data is stored
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

time.sleep(5)
```

Things to note:

**Ensure Chrome is Closed**:

- Make sure that all instances of Chrome are closed before running your Selenium script. Sometimes, if Chrome is running in the background or doesn't shut down correctly, it can cause issues when trying to start a new instance.

**Check ChromeDriver Version**:

- Ensure that your ChromeDriver version matches the version of Google Chrome installed on your system. If they don't match, it can lead to compatibility issues.

**Demo**:
[image: demo]